# Cannot get "@media screen and" to work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to make an adjustment to my H1 tags when the screen is at 480px width or less. Right now it's a very tall headline when viewed on mobile so I decided to add a custom @media to resolve this. Please ignore the actual CSS values as I am using drastic changes to make it obvious if the changes actually do happen.

In my CSS I tried:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .intro h1 {
        font-size: .5em;
        line-height: 60px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
}
```

And used this in my head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I've tried several variations of the viewport code, and several variations of the @media code. Including:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
     .intro h1 {
        font-size: .5em;
        line-height: 60px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
```

and

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
     .intro h1 {
        font-size: .5em;
        line-height: 60px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
```

Etc. etc. I should mention I am using bootstrap and I am wondering if that could be causing some conflict? I have never tried to implement custom @media code with a CSS framework like bootstrap before so I am not sure of the rules here! When I view on my phone, or drag my browser as narrow as it'll get, nothing changes other than my H1 headline stacking up with the same huge font instead of getting smaller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dude.... you nailed it. I didn't even think about that! THANK YOU. This has seriously been 90 minutes of "why do I do web design". I feel so dumb.

Not sure where the previous comment went... but I resolved this thanks to it. I didn't have the @media code below the default CSS code.

Comment: The css positioning? I remove it because i thought it was a stupid comment :) turns out it was correct :) Well your welcome and if you don't mind I would like to make it an answer so I can get more points :)

Comment: thanks @MatthewHammond! I haven't done a lot of responsive work outside of bootstrap or foundation so that's a rule I'll not soon forget! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media queries look correct, make sure you have the media queries after your normal CSS, as it will always use the last set CSS style.

Comment: And if that shouldn't work, consider removing the word `-device`.